# Adding images to buttons from Imagelist on a toolstrip?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know why Microsoft got rid of the ImageList property on toolbars? Where is the best place to assign an imagelist manually? Would I be able to get the images to display during design time if the only images I can add or change is from a local resource or project resource file? How do I get the specific imagelist index to show on the buttons in toolstrip during design time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is still there for `ToolBars` but `ToolBars` are being replaced by `ToolStrips`.

One of the [`ToolStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) subclasses is [`MenueStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Both `ToolStrip` and `MenueStrip`, have an [`ImageList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.imagelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

However, for reasons unknown, the `ImageList` property **doesn't show up** in the property tab:

[image]

**However** you can set it in code and `Intellisense` will help you..:

[image]

Unfortunately this will not help when working in the designer. One can subclass `ToolStrip` to expose the `ImageList` but the `ToolStripItems` don't expose their `ImageIndex` properties either, so this doesn't help.

All `ToolStripItems` have an `Image` property, though, and after adding your `Images` to the resources you can pull them in from there.

Looks like this is how we are **supposed** to do it now..? Wouldn't it be nice to have a word about this in the documentation. Or maybe someday soon (most likely sooner) in SO Documentation?!

I think this is a case of [nudging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nudge_theory) us away from `ImageList`; one of the advantages is that now you can give each item a **different** image size, some square others wider..

Comment: I have an imagelist on my form with a set of images. I would like to see my images on buttons during design time though. Is this not possible anymore on a toolstrip? Will they only be visible during runtime?

Comment: See my updated answer: The property is only accessible in code, not in the designer, so to see the images in the designer you will have to go for images in resources .-(

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right. I know you pretty much already answered my question so I marked it as correct already, but if it's not too much. How exactly would I switch the image on a toolstrip button programmatically? I have a button that I want to switch from Play to Stop icons every time it's clicked. Originally I would just change the imageindex, how would I change it to another image in the resources file?

Comment: Sure. Assuming you have a `bool playing`and have added two resource files you can switch: `using System.Resources;.. .. .. toolStripButton1.Image = playing 
               ? (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("playImage")
               : (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("StopImage");` Make sure you get the names right (no extension) as there won't be a warning.